# Does every import in TypeScript require a *.d.ts file?

Tags: typescript

I'm migrating my `React` project from `Babel` to `TypeScript`. It seems like everytime I `import` something `TypeScript` yells at me:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module './some-file'.`

this is for both external modules (via `npm`) or local other files in my project (that have not been yet `TypeScript`yfied)

Is there a way to tell `TypeScript` compiler to treat anything I import as `any` so I dont have to provide definitions for them?

Comment: you need to include definitely typed typescript file for external module. Typings( .d.ts) file for most of the common library are available on https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped. You need to include these .d.ts file in your typings folder and use them using ///<reference path="filePathName" />

Comment: @Ajay not every module has definately typed definitions, also I seem to need `d.ts` definitions for local project files, I'm looking for ways to avoid that

Comment: I recommend living with the "errors" until you finish the typification process, otherwise you'll be declaring definitions that will become obsolete.  Make sure you turn off noImplicityAny.  You'll still get js output.

Comment: @CoreyAlix my build fails with message above, no js output

Comment: What syntax are you using? `import * as foo from "bar"` or `var foo = require("bar")`?

Comment: @rgvassar I'm using import * ... syntax

Comment: @dark_ruby Share your source with me.  You will have some js output if you have something to generate.  Even this generates js output:

`import "invalid/path/name";`

Answer (score 0):

YES.

You can declare modules yourself but it can be difficult to manage the module names when using relative paths:

```
declare module "ol/OpenLayers-combined" {
    var ol: any;
    export = ol;
}
```

Here are the current-day TSC option:

```
Version 1.8.7
Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ...]

Examples: tsc hello.ts
          tsc --out file.js file.ts
          tsc @args.txt

Options:
 --allowJs                           Allow javascript files to be compiled.
 --allowSyntheticDefaultImports      Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking.
 --allowUnreachableCode              Do not report errors on unreachable code.
 --allowUnusedLabels                 Do not report errors on unused labels.
 -d, --declaration                   Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file.
 --experimentalDecorators            Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators.
 --forceConsistentCasingInFileNames  Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file.
 -h, --help                          Print this message.
 --init                              Initializes a TypeScript project and creates a tsconfig.json file.
 --jsx KIND                          Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve' or 'react'
 --mapRoot LOCATION                  Specifies the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations.
 -m KIND, --module KIND              Specify module code generation: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd' or 'es2015'
 --moduleResolution                  Specifies module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6).
 --newLine NEWLINE                   Specifies the end of line sequence to be used when emitting files: 'CRLF' (dos) or 'LF' (unix).
 --noEmit                            Do not emit outputs.
 --noEmitOnError                     Do not emit outputs if any errors were reported.
 --noFallthroughCasesInSwitch        Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement.
 --noImplicitAny                     Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type.
 --noImplicitReturns                 Report error when not all code paths in function return a value.
 --noImplicitUseStrict               Do not emit 'use strict' directives in module output.
 --outDir DIRECTORY                  Redirect output structure to the directory.
 --outFile FILE                      Concatenate and emit output to single file.
 --preserveConstEnums                Do not erase const enum declarations in generated code.
 --pretty KIND                       Stylize errors and messages using color and context. (experimental)
 -p DIRECTORY, --project DIRECTORY   Compile the project in the given directory.
 --reactNamespace                    Specifies the object invoked for createElement and __spread when targeting 'react' JSX emit
 --removeComments                    Do not emit comments to output.
 --rootDir LOCATION                  Specifies the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir.
 --sourceMap                         Generates corresponding '.map' file.
 --sourceRoot LOCATION               Specifies the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations.
 --suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors    Suppress noImplicitAny errors for indexing objects lacking index signatures.
 -t VERSION, --target VERSION        Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', or 'ES2015' (experimental)
 -v, --version                       Print the compiler's version.
 -w, --watch                         Watch input files.
 @<file>                             Insert command line options and files from a file.
```

Notice the noEmitOnError options.  If that is not set to true then even invalid typescript should compile to javascript.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to not to declare a type for every imported module

Comment: What your asking is for the compiler not to warn you when you've made a reference to an invalid module.  Until you declare a module you're going to see a warning (there are no TS errors, really).  You should avoid the import statement altogether and use raw require.